# Parsing JSON to string key and values

Tags: json, dart

Is there a way to parse a JSON as a `Map<String, String>` instead of `Map<String, dynamic>` when using Dart's `json.decode`.

For example with JSON of:

```
{
 'a': 2,
 'b': 'c'
}
```

It would parse into:

```
{
 'a': '2',
 'b': 'c'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, no. The code for decoding a `Map` starts with a `Map<String, dynamic>` and adds values as they are read, so there is no way to make the value type more specific.

Look into these for other options:

- Create a new `Map` with the right type from any source map: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Map/Map.from.html – you pay a one-time cost for copying the values.
- Create a type-safe view over an existing `Map` - https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Map/cast.html – no copy cost, but you pay the overhead of wrapping/casting on each access of the original Map

Comment: Since parsing an unquoted `2` as a string would be a violation of the JSON specification, that's not something the JSON parse will do for you. It sounds like you need to convert the map. You can do: `var jsonMap = jsonDecode(...); Map<String, String> myMap = Map.fromEntries(jsonMap.entries.map((e) => MapEntry(e.key, "${e.value}")));`.